# Permission denied Exception while Running Embedded ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using https://github.com/allegro/embedded-elasticsearch for writing integration tests for Elastic. After initial setup when I ran the tests this plugin downloaded the elastic instance successfully but start giving **permission denied errors.**

**My Java version :**

```
openjdk 11.0.2 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

**Full Stack Trace**

```
Exception in thread "EmbeddedElsHandler" pl.allegro.tech.embeddedelasticsearch.EmbeddedElasticsearchStartupException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/var/folders/ql/403xvvqs42v00xlnqgr6d8540000gn/T/embedded-elasticsearch-temp-dir/elasticsearch-6.6.0/bin/elasticsearch": error=13, Permission denied
    at pl.allegro.tech.embeddedelasticsearch.ElasticServer.lambda$startElasticProcess$6(ElasticServer.java:89)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/var/folders/ql/403xvvqs42v00xlnqgr6d8540000gn/T/embedded-elasticsearch-temp-dir/elasticsearch-6.6.0/bin/elasticsearch": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at pl.allegro.tech.embeddedelasticsearch.ElasticServer.lambda$startElasticProcess$6(ElasticServer.java:80)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 3 more
```

**My Embedded Elastic Configuration**

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
 final EmbeddedElastic embeddedElastic = EmbeddedElastic.builder()
 .withElasticVersion("6.6.0")
 .withSetting(PopularProperties.TRANSPORT_TCP_PORT, "9200")
 .withSetting(PopularProperties.CLUSTER_NAME, "partner_portal_elasticsearch_cluster")
 .withPlugin("analysis-stempel") // Commented this line, with this line permission deined came while installing the plugin
  .build();

     try {
         embeddedElastic.start();
        System.out.println("Embedded Elastic Search instance started................");
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
```

ElasticSearch bin Folder looks like this (for permission reference)
[image]

Comment: I think you do not have net set x permission to plugin directory                                   find /usr/share/elasticsearch -type d -exec chmod +x {} \;

Comment: There is no such directory : `find: /usr/share/elasticsearch: No such file or directory`

Comment: are you using windows or linux this is the linux path.

Comment: @DHARMENDRASINGH Added the bin folder image,

Comment: @DHARMENDRASINGH I am on Mac-OS

Comment: make sure all file in /var/folders/ql/403xvvqs42v00xlnqgr6d8540000gn/T/embedded-elasticsearch-temp-dir/elasticsearch-6.6.0/bin/ have elasticsearch user permission.

Comment: For reference follow this link https://discuss.elastic.co/t/facing-issue-to-start-elasticsearch-permission-denied/131970

Comment: @DHARMENDRASINGH This links talks about the user is unable to start the elastic instance at all (not from the terminal as well). I can successfully start the elastic instance from the downloaded directory using : `/bin/elasticsearch -d -p elastic_pid -Ecluster.name=neeraj_elasticsearch_cluster -Enode.name=neeraj_elastic_cluster_node`

Answer (score 0):

If you are making use of systemd daemon files, and a WorkingDirectory entry, then make sure it ends with a slash ('/').